# NavigationView set selected item as checked

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I am using NavigationView from the support library. I have a BaseActivity that Activity A and B extend from.

By default app starts with Activity A. When user clicks on a a drawer menu item, i start activity B.

After starting activity B. how can i set the menu item corresponding with it to be highlighted as checked?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

Now with the latest update to the support library, you can do:

```
mDrawer.setCheckedItem(R.id.drawer_profile);
```

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/navigation-drawer-how-set-selected-item.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

Call this method after you call setNavDrawer();

The getItem(int index) method gets the MenuItem then you can call the setChecked(true); on that MenuItem, all you left to do and find out is which element index does the home the default have, and replace the 0 with that index.

Comment: Great it's working. is it possible to replace the getItem(1) with a getItem(R.id...)?

Comment: @TareKhoury no as I explained the 0 is the index of the menu item that you want to set Checked ( highlighted ), R.id.... gets some ID from the R file and that might not be an element ( valid index ) of the Menus list.

Comment: In future, rather than re-post your answer, vote to close the question as a duplicate, please.

Comment: Use... `findItem(int id)` if you want to use R.id...

Comment: This does not work for me, what is the setNavDrawer() method?

Comment: Sorry Im new to this, android that is, been doing ios. Where is the setNavDrawer()?!